# Cumulocity beginner's question: How to do a realtime analytics

Tags: cumulocity

I'm trying to take my forst steps using cumulocity.
I've got my phone registered as device and can even see it, but how can I now use those nifty "cel" statements?
Can I just enter them somewhere? Do I have to deploy something?

The [documentation](https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/administration#business-rules) mentions an event processing tab:
[image]

but I don't have that:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: It's an optional feature. If you do not see if, drop a note to us at support.cumulocity.com with your URL and support can activate it.

Comment: Great! Could you please post this as an answer so I can mark it and you get the reputation points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an optional feature. If you do not see if, drop a note to us at support.cumulocity.com with your URL and support can activate it.